# Identify immigration record for John Kelly, Ireland to Michigan about 1840's?

Tags: united-states, 19th-century, immigration, ireland, michigan

John Kelly or John W Kelly was born in Ireland about 1833.

- He likely immigrated prior to 1855 and married Mary Ling (also Irish) after arriving in the US.
- By 1860 he was a Teamster in Battle Creek, Michigan and may also have worked for Grand Trunk RR.
- He died 01 Sep. 1884.
- He had several children, all born in the US.

  - Michael b 1857,
  - Ella b 1863,
  - Mary b act 1855 and
  - possibly William b 1869.

Three ships carried a John Kelly of about the correct age:

- ABRABIAN left Liverpool on 18 Jun 1846
- RAPPAHANOCK left Liverpool on 11 Nov 1846
- FLORDIAN left Londonderry on 24 May 1847

How can I be certain of the US immigration record for my GGG Grandfather, John Kelly, so that I can trace his earlier life?

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE!  This question needs work because it is unclear what you are asking.   You start with John Kelly and then close with asking about his son Michael, and you don't say what information you are looking for.  Please read the material in the [help], including [How do I ask a good question?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and look at the other questions on the site to see if there are other answers already here that can help you. You can use the edit link under your question to edit it.

Comment: Point taken regarding Micheal.  Does not "Any suggestions on tracing....." cover what I'm after?

Comment: I suspect that you will find a large number of men named John Kelly may have been born in Ireland during the period that you are looking at.  That does not mean you should stop looking for a baptism/birth record there but I think it will be far more productive working from the after emigration side first.  I'll edit your question to focus it on trying to locate his immigration record but part of that will be trying to assess all the possible records that you have for him after that emigration.

Comment: Is the 1860 record the first that you have for him?  What is its source and content?

Comment: Broad questions e.g. "anything about" don't attract good answers.  Specific questions are more likely to get a response. Your question could also be improved by letting us know what records you have already looked at. Where did all the information in your question come from? You may have overlooked clues in the records you already have.

Comment: ALCON,  The 1860 US Census listed him being in Battle Creek, MI.  Thereafter there are several references to him in the Battle Creek City Directory.  He and his wife (Mary) are buried at Oak Hill Cemetery in Battle Creek.  The three ships listed were gleaned from US Immigration records.  Lastly, John and Mary Kelly/Kelley (of Ireland) were listed on a document relating to Ella Kelly's death certificate.

Comment: Ancestry.com has a tree showing John Kelly married to a Mary Burn but I have had no response, as yet, from the posting family.  Lastly, John and Mary Kelly/Kelley (of Ireland) were listed on a document relating to Ella Kelly's death certificate.